# Custom Styling for getOptionLable in AutoComplete of Material UI

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I want to  have a custom look in my dropdown i have all neecessary changes my code is as follow:

```
> export const Dropdown = props => {
> const fieldProps = { ...props };
> delete fieldProps.formik;
> const {
> name,
> formik: { values, handleChange, touched, errors, status },
> label,
> placeholder,
> disabled,
> highlight
> props;
> 
> const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
> const error =
> touched[name] && Boolean(errors[name] || status[name] || status.root);
> const message = touched[name] && (errors[name] || status[name]);
> return (
>     <ClickAwayListener
> onClickAway={() => setOpen(false)}
> data-test='component-Dropdown'>
>       <Autocomplete
> open={open}
> autoComplete
> value={values[name]}
> error={error}
> ListboxComponent={MenuList}
> getOptionLabel={option =>
> highlight && option && option.label && option.value
>             ? `${option.value} - ${option.label}`
> option.label || placeholder
>         }
> renderInput={params => {
> return (
>             <>
>               <TextField
> required={props.required}
> error={error}
>                 {...params}
> fullWidth
> label={label}
>               />
>               <InputAdornment
> position='end'
> style={{ position: 'absolute', right: 25 }}>
>                 <ErrorTooltip message={message} />
>               </InputAdornment>
>             </>
>           );
>         }}
> renderOption={option =>
> highlight ? (
>             <div>
>               <span style={{ color: highlight ? '#ff6000' : 'inherit' }}>
>                 {option.value}
>               </span>{' '}
>               - {option.label}
>             </div>
>           ) : (
> option.label
>           )
>         }
> closeIcon={!error && <SearchIcon />}
```

where while option render the value and label is displaying correctly i.e. Value in orange color and label in primary color  also working once I added it is it displaying also in same way.

but when I select it the styling vanishes and the selected text convert in primary color
kindly find the screenshot for the same I tried to wrap the text in span but it started to show up in the selected area as well if not getting warning saying that needed string but getting object